# Automatic class creation error during IOS development

Tags: swift

[image]

As shown in the picture above, only the view controller can be checked within automatic.
I'd like to add CalendarCell.
It's the same even if I delete the application and create it after saving it, so what did I do wrong?

Comment: What's in the Top Level Objects section?

Comment: I am a student who is experiencing IOS development for the first time. I'm just going to make it and watch it, but it's a problem with YouTube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abbWOYFZd68 doing it until 3:15 in the calendar tutorial process. I thought I copied it properly, but there was an error, so I'm so sad.

Comment: Yes, you’ve got the cell highlighted, so only the view controller will be shown under “automatic”. But add some subview (label or whatever) within the cell, then select that subview, and then “automatic” will show both the view controller and the cell class as options…